# python socket, invalid argument

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, sockets

I'm working with an [ethernet enabled relay](https://www.controlanything.com/Relay/Device/R130PL_ETHERNET). Trying to communicate with it with python over a socket. I'm seeing very interesting behavior and I don't think it is device related. Below is the code that fails. The error I'm getting is `[Errno 22] Invalid argument`

```
    self.ip_addr = <some address>
    self.port = <some port>
    self.max_attempt_cnt = <some count>
    self.sleep_interval = <some interval>
    try_cnt=0
    skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)        
    while True:
        try:
            skt.connect((self.ip_addr, int(self.port)))
            break
        except socket.error as e:
            try_cnt+=1
            if (self.max_attempt_cnt > 0) and (try_cnt > self.max_attempt_cnt):
                msg = 'Maximum connection attempt count of {} is exceeded'.format(
                        self.max_attempt_cnt
                        )
                raise ConnectionAttemptCountExceededError(msg)
            time.sleep(self.sleep_interval)

    <do stuff 0>
    <do stuff 1>
    <do stuff 2>
```

If I move my defition of `skt` inside the `while` loop, i.e like the following:

```
    while True:
        try:
            skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            skt.connect((self.ip_addr, int(self.port)))
            break
```

The issue disappears.

I know there is a different way to write this code but that is not what I'm asking.

My question is why the code is failing when the socket is created outside the loop and why it works when the socket is created inside the loop?

**EDIT**

I realized that I didn't mention that this code does work on `Windows`, but it doesn't work on a `Mac` machine, which is what I'm using.

Comment: It works fine for me (  python 2.7 , windows ) , can you include the traceback ?

Comment: @t.m.adam I should have mentioned that it does work in Windows, but I'm running my code on a Mac.

Comment: So it's an os thing apparently . Have you tried linux ?

Comment: @t.m.adam Same as OSX. Windows implements sockets differently. It makes sense that Linux and OSX match.

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge, i tested it on debian and it works ok. On both win and linux, i tried to connect on localhost:80  with apache on / off and it works as expected in any case.. Can you post the full code and traceback ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `connect` man page that comes with Linux (debian / Jessie)

> If `connect()` fails, consider the state of the socket as unspecified.
>   Portable applications should close the socket and create a new one  for
>   reconnecting.

Based on this, the invalid argument error message refers to the given file descriptor that corresponds to a socket that not in usable state.

Comment: Thank you! It takes me a hour to debug!